# itext7 pdfHTML add page title without PAC tool warnings

Tags: c#, itext7

I'm going to create accessibility pdf using itext7. While adding page title using  tag in html file, it gets warning,  "**Possibly inappropriate use of P Structure element**". The reason is iText is adding extra

tag inside the  tag.
HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <body>
         <h1>Title</h1>
      </body>
    </html>
```

When I generate the pdf using iText7 pdfHTML add-on, it displays as below;

```
<h1><p><span>Title
```

`<p>` tag is the reason for the warnings.
Then it returns PAC tool warning. Not to get any warnings, it should be,

```
<h1><span>Title
```

Please help me to resolve the issue. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize the corresponding tag worker if you want to. You can get a resultant layout element produced by the tag worker and manipulate it. In particular, you can explicitly direct an element to not create a node in the tag structure tree if you want to.

So for your example the structure of layout elements is roughly `Div <- Paragraph <- "Title"`. What the code below does is finds a paragraph and sets its accessibility role to `null` so that a node is not created in the tag tree.

Custom tag worker:

```
private static class CustomH1TagWorker extends HTagWorker {
    public CustomH1TagWorker(IElementNode element, ProcessorContext context) {
        super(element, context);
    }

    @Override
    public IPropertyContainer getElementResult() {
        IPropertyContainer baseResult = super.getElementResult();
        if (baseResult instanceof BlockElement && ((BlockElement) baseResult).getChildren().size() == 1
             && ((BlockElement) baseResult).getChildren().get(0) instanceof Paragraph) {
            ((Paragraph) ((BlockElement) baseResult).getChildren().get(0)).getAccessibilityProperties().setRole(null);
        }
        return baseResult;
    }
}
```

Creating `ConverterProperties` and tweaking `TagWorkerFactory`. Make sure to pass converter properties to `HtmlConverter`.

```
ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();

properties.setTagWorkerFactory(new DefaultTagWorkerFactory() {
    @Override
    public ITagWorker getCustomTagWorker(IElementNode tag, ProcessorContext context) {
        if (TagConstants.H1.equals(tag.name())) {
            return new CustomH1TagWorker(tag, context);
        }
        return super.getCustomTagWorker(tag, context);
    }
});

HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(inputStream, pdfDocument, properties);
```

Comment: Thanks so much Alexey. It worked for me and it is really helpful.